# Can't send mail through ssl with my virtual domains from an external webmail

Tags: debian, ssl, postfix, smtp, tls

I having issues with postfix to send mail through SSL from an external webmail.
I have several domain setup on my server configured in postfix with mysql. When I send mail with my main domain domain1.com everything works fine but if send mail from domain2.com I get this into my log:

Note that if I disable SSL on the webmail it works.

```
connect from unknown[78.209.78.XXX]
timeout after UNKNOWN from unknown[78.209.78.XXX]
disconnect from unknown[78.209.78.XXX]
```

Here is my main.cf:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no
disable_vrfy_command = yes
smtpd_helo_required = yes
append_dot_mydomain = no

mydomain= domain1.com
myhostname = domain1.com
myorigin = $mydomain
mydestination = XXX.kimsufi.com, localhost.kimsufi.com, localhost
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128

alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all

virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/alias-maps.cf
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000

smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/smtpd.key
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/smtpd.crt
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/ssl/cacert.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom

mail local si actif
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,
 permit_mynetworks,
 reject_unauth_destination,
 check_policy_service unix:private/policy, # SPF
 permit
 #check_relay_domains

smtpd_sasl_auth_enable  = yes
smtpd_sasl_type         = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path         = private/authnoactive, mutual_auth
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes

# DKIM
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 6
smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:8891
non_smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:8891
```

Note that on the webmail, I've set the smtp server to mail.domain1.com since I've read that I have to use the domain defined as Common Name in the tls certificate .

What I want is to make it work with SSL. Any idea about why it's not working ?

**Edit**

---

Here is new informations:

It seem that the problem is not related to domain1 or domain2 but occur only with new configurations. I had a domain that was setup since more than a year and everything was working fine. I removed it from my webmail and reconfigured it and now, I can't send mail.

While I was configuring it, I saw that it was asking me to use my https certificat and not the postfix one. So maybe the problem come from there but I don't know how to solve it.

Here is my apache conf:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
  include /etc/apache2/domain.conf

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  include /etc/apache2/domain.conf

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/cert-domain.com.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/domain.com.key
  SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/GandiStandardSSLCA.pem
  SSLVerifyClient None
</VirtualHost>
```

Also if I do openssl s_client -connect localhost:465 I get that:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
11508:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:607:
```

I don't know if it's normal for a self signed certificat.

Comment: Can you post the error log from the webmail client? It would be nice to see what the client doesn't like..

Comment: The webmail client tell me that the smtp server mail.domain1.com don't answer (I've just edit the log message in my post because it looks like I paste the wrong part). If I connect from roundcube on the server it works. POP and IMAP also works.

Comment: When you say send with, do you mean send as user@domain1.com works, but sending as user1@domain2.com does not?

Comment: Yes, sending as user1@domain2.com doesn't work (except if I disable SSL on the webmail client) and sending as user@domain1.com always works.

Comment: Hmm, what program are you using, roundcube? Do the server where the webmail client is installed have logs that might give more clues? /var/log/httpd/error.log, /var/log/messages/ etc?

Comment: Sorry I miss your comment. I'm using Apple mail. Can't find any clue from that logs but I've updated my post. I think the problem is that my server mess up between my apache and my postfix certificats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postfix is not listening in `smtpd_tls_wrappermode` on port 465, but rather as a standard smtp server.

Your `master.cf` should contain a (multipart) line simliar to

> smtps     inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
>     -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
>     -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
>     -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
>     -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject

However, it likely only has

> smtps     inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd